# No component found for view with name " RNSVGViewBox "

Tags: svg, charts, react-native, victory-charts

I just followed the documentation and installed victory native (to be able to generate charts) following this link https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native

I also installed react-native-svg and linked it.

I keep getting this error although I'm following this https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/native and I just started by the first example.
According to the documentation

[image]

And since I'm using react native 0.42.0 and react 15.4.2 so I installed react-native-svg 4.5.0 but it's not working and I get this

[image]

I tried to uninstall it and unlink it and I changed to the newer version but still getting the same error.

Maybe this is not a react-native-svg issue and it's a victory-native issue.

Comment: did you build the project again after installing this library?